# Unable to run Grails 3.0.4 (Windows)

Tags: grails

I am a Grails user. I downloaded Grails 3.0.4, changed the enviroment path to its and tried to run it by typed "grails" on windows command but there was an error show that,

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/grails-3.0.4/lib/org.springframework/
springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
Error occured during initialization of VM agen library failed to init : instrument
```

Before, I used Grails 2.4.2, it worked normally.

Comment: Weird - my 3.0.4 install has springloaded version 1.2.4.RELEASE. Try deleting your current one and reinstalling.

Comment: I think the error message is self explanatory. Make sure the `springloaded` jar is not corrupted and accessible. If the problem persists re-download or manually download that file (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.0.RELEASE)

Comment: Take care, the last versions of Grails are unstable on Windows. I guess you are using Windows 7 or more?